# Posted results will not save to the mysql database, even when no record exists

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

I am using the following with a quiz I am making, it checks the table to see if the user has already posted the answer to the question and isn't hammering the submit button, the problem I am having is its not posting the info to the database for some odd reason. If I take out the if statement and the first database looking and just post the data it works fine, but when I check the result of the first query first, it doesn't appear to work, even if the user hasn't submitted an answer yet.

```
 <?php
 $quizID = $_GET['quiz'];
$userID = $_GET['user'];
$quizselectanswer = $_POST['quizselectanswer'];
$cf_created = date("y/m/d");
$questionID = $_POST['questionID'];

// Check to see if user answered question already
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT questionID,userID FROM itsnb_chronoforms_data_answerquiz WHERE     questionID='$questionID' AND userID='$userID' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
if (empty($row))
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO itsnb_chronoforms_data_answerquiz (cf_created,     questionID,quizselectanswer,quizID, userID)
    VALUES ('$cf_created', '$questionID', '$quizselectanswer', '$quizID','$userID')") 
    or     
    die(mysql_error());
}else{

}
}
?>
```

My database looks like this `itsnb_chronoforms_data_answerquiz`  `cf_id`, `cf_uid`, `cf_created`, `cf_modified` ,`cf_ipaddress` ,`cf_user_id` ,`questionID`, `quizselectanswer`, `quizID` ,`userID`.

Comment: It's not particularly well formed code full stop.

Comment: Im no expert, so if there is a better way, id like to know :)

Comment: did you try checking the error by mysql_error()

Comment: I have mysql_error error in there already, but no error comes up.

Comment: I see massive potential for **SQL injections** and use of **deprecated mysql extension**. Since you already touch the code, why not fix this issues too?

Comment: Im going to sanitise the GETS and POSTS once its working, I dont know how to use PDO so this is the only option at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this it may help you

```
// Check to see if user answered question already
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itsnb_chronoforms_data_answerquiz WHERE questionID='$questionID' AND userID='$userID' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(!empty($row)) 
{
    while($row){
        //some statement
    }
}else{
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO itsnb_chronoforms_data_answerquiz (cf_created, questionID,quizselectanswer, quizID, userID)
    VALUES ("'.$cf_created.'", "'.$questionID.'", "'.$quizselectanswer.'", "'.$quizID.'","'.$userID.'")') or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Php syntax is wrong for mysql_query, use this:

    mysql_query('INSERT INTO itsnb_chronoforms_data_answerquiz (cf_created, questionID,quizselectanswer, quizID, userID)
            VALUES ("'.$cf_created.'", "'.$questionID.'", "'.$quizselectanswer.'", '.$quizID.','.$userID.')') or die(mysql_error());

I presume userID and quizID are integers.

Comment: When I use that I get "Unknown column 'WmuQiV1wtN' in 'field list'"  WmuQiV1wtN is the quizID from GET

Comment: @IainSimpson I have update the my answer have a look. As you say I assume `quizid` as string

Comment: I now get Unknown column 'testuserid' in 'field list' -------- The url looks like this by the way ------ nextquestion=60&user=testuserid&quiz=WmuQiV1wtN&chronoform=answerquiz&event=submit

Comment: @IainSimpson same with `userid` I assume it as integer but as per your url it seems to be a string,check my answer now.If again you have some problem can you paste the full url with structure of your table.

Comment: This inserts the data now, but if I hit back and then try submitting the question again, on submit I get HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I removed the WHILE and it's working now !, thanks very much for your help :-)